# is it possible to catch fatal or parse errors in php

Tags: php, debugging, try-catch

let's say i have this code:

`$a = 3 //forgot semicolon`

is there a way to prevent the script from crashing,
 detect the error, 
call a custom function that will record the php error inside a custom error log file instead of the default php error log in php.ini, 
and also record this in the database.

I have tried the set_error_handler function, and try and catch but these are not suitable for this kind of scenario.

Comment: server creates one log_file

Comment: Can a fatal injury be recovered from?

Answer (score 0):

> The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined
>   function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING,
>   E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the
>   file where set_error_handler() is called.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php